# Resque poping instead of failing

Tags: ruby, resque, resque-retry

I have a simple code for ruby- resque.

But due to some code issues, some jobs fail.

The problem is that they do not appear in failed jobs, they  just disappear (once job is taken from the queue, it's poped, so it's removed).

How can I make resque to put the job in failed position?

Comment: That weird what does you see in resque UI

Comment: I see the problem. Once the job is taken form the queue, it is removed from redis. Once it fails it's back in the redis in failed jobs. But the moment you stop the worker (ctrl+c) it doesn't have time to put it back in the failed jobs

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. Once the job is taken form the queue, it is removed from redis. Once it fails it's back in the redis in failed jobs. But the moment you stop the worker (ctrl+c) it doesn't have time to put it back in the failed jobs